# Added DataKey to recognize my primary key column and INSERT INTO doe

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I added DataKey to recognize my primary key, idt.

The INSERT INTO still does not store the data in the database.

My database has 5 columns idt,datetime,col1,col2 and col3.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    connStr = "connectionstring works"
    cmdStr = "UPDATE test SET [datetime]=@datetime,[col1]=@col1,[col2]=@col2,[col3]=@col3 WHERE [idt]=@idt;"
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idt", GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", DateTime.Now)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col3", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
    ViewState("edit") = e.RowIndex
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
```

ShowGrid() works and contains

```
GridView1.EditIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState("edit"))
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="Gridview1_OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="Gridview1_OnRowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_OnRowUpdating" 
   DataKeyNames="idt">
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `insert into` anywhere in your code.